# sublime text 2: how to add a menu item to run non-current build system?

Tags: javascript, build, editor, sublimetext2, mocha.js

I've added a new build system in Sublime Text 2, which runs a mocha test suite for me (doing a simple 'make test').  However, I do not want this to be my active build system (because I already have an active JSHint build system which I want to stay in place).

Instead, what I simply want to do is to add a new menu item under the Tools menu which will run my mocha test suites. In other words, Tools/Build should run my "active" JSHint build system, and only by selecting Tools/Mocha (where Mocha is a new menu item I add) should I run my mocha test suite.

This should be simple but I've spent hours on what should be a simple task so hopefully someone can point out how to do this.

Comment: Does your build file have a `.sublime-build` extension?

Comment: Yes.  I can create a new build file fine.  The problem is that I don't want to run that new build file as my default one.  I want to add a menu item command that runs it.